# Alias for network drive

Tags: network, alias

In the `Finder > Connect To Server` window I have an IP address I connect to. Is there a way to make a nickname or alias for this server?

Comment: I would suggest doing it in your hosts file, but I don't have my mac with me right now, so I can't confirm that works...

Comment: What sort of server? and is internet or local?

Comment: local. windows SMB. 192.168.x.y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create aliases directly to network shares the normal way, by right-clicking the mounted share and choosing "Create Alias." If you want to create an alias/bookmark to the server so you can select which share to mount every time, do the following:

1. Open Safari
2. Bookmark any page to make a new bookmark
3. Edit the bookmark to point to your server and service. For Windows sharing, the URL would start with smb:// followed by your IP address, ex smb://192.168.0.5
4. Drag the bookmark out of the Safari bookmarks view onto your desktop

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
10.0.0.1     alias.local
```

Comment: Better to use directory services see http://superuser.com/questions/245354/what-is-windows-hosts-file-alternative-for-osx/245364#245364

Answer (score 0):

Note that the accepted answer, which was the best answer at the time, is now a bit out of date. In fact, there was an intermediary method between it and my recommendation, but that is also outdated.

The first time you connect to the server, use the **Finder > Connect to Server** method as in the opening post question.

*To create a permanent shortcut* to either the shared network drive or to any folder on that drive, simply click and drag the folder icon to your desktop/Finder location whilst holding down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>.